# Trigger event based on specific inputs into a textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to trigger a JS event when there are four consecutive linebreaks inside of a textarea.

The situation causing this would either be that a person presses the RETURN key four times, a person pastes text that contains four line breaks, or they delete some content (ie a paragraph) that results in four consecutive linebreaks.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution:

```
document.getElementById("textArea").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  var numberOfLineBreaks = (this.value.match(/\n/g)||[]).length;
  if (numberOfLineBreaks === 4) {
    console.log("4 consecutive Lines!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that easy solution:

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  if (this.value.includes('\n\n\n\n')) {
    console.log("4 consecutive return!");
  }
});
```

```css
#myInput {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myInput"></textarea>
```

You're lucky that I was interested in the subject, and that it's really easy to do!
I'm pretty sure you can do it by yourself next time.